# Cardinality of $\{ f\in C'[0,1] : f(0)=0, f(1)=1, |f'(t)|\leq 1 \forall t\in[0,1]\}$... NBHM $2007$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Question is to find :

What is the cardinality of the following set :

$$A=\{ f\in C'[0,1] : f(0)=0, f(1)=1, |f'(t)|\leq 1 \forall t\in[0,1]\}$$

I would like to see for some time that all $f\in C'[0,1]$ which i am looking for are just polynomials as any continuous function can be approximated uniformly by polynomials.

with $f(0)=0$ condition I would like to say $f$ do not have constant term.

with the condition that $f'(t)$ being bounded by $1$ I would like to say that $f$ do not have higher powers

ie., suppose $f=x^3+x^2+1$ then, $f'=3x^2+2$ whihch is not bounded by $1$

I do not really mean this should how the polynomials of higher degrees look like but if $f$ has degree $n>1$ then, $f(x)=nx^{n-1}+g(x)$ and this would be not bounded by $1$.

I have not yet used $|f'(t)|\leq 1 \forall t\in[0,1]$ but i belive this would also give same result.

Just for simplicity Suppose $f(x)=x^3$ then, $|f'(t)|=\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|}=\frac{|x^3-y^3|}{|x-y|}=|x^2+xy+y^2|$

But i can choose $x,y$ accordingly suhc that this is not bounded by $1$

So, $f(x)$ do not have higher powers and because $f(1)=1$, coefficient of $x$ has to be $1$

i.e., $$A=\{ f\in C'[0,1] : f(0)=0, f(1)=1, |f'(t)|\leq 1 \forall t\in[0,1]\}=\{x\}$$

I would like some one to verify if this is sufficient or do i have to rewrite the arguments (I am sure i have to, but i am not sure how to do so).

Please help me to clear this ambiguity.. Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Suppose that $f(c)\ne c$ for some $c\in(0,1)$. If $f(c)>c$, the mean value theorem ensures that there is an $x\in(0,c)$ such that $f\,'(x)>1$, and if $f(c)<c$, it ensures that there is an $x\in(c,1)$ such that $f\,'(x)>1$. Thus, the identity function is the only member of $A$.

Comment: :) I really like this :) SO, we are just using $|f'(x)|\leq 1$ and nothing more right... ? $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$ might have forced you to get the idea that you have to suppose $f(c)\neq c$ for some $c\in (0,1)$ (for contradiction though)... Sir, Do you want to say some thing more.. I would be thankful to learn.. :)

Comment: @Praphulla: What makes it work is that the slope of the secant line between the endpoints $\langle 0,0\rangle$ and $\langle 1,1\rangle$ is the same as the limit on $f\,'(x)$. Thus, if the graph moves off that line, one side of it or the other must have an average slope greater than $1$. Then I just had to check that the hypotheses of the mean value theorem were all in place.

Comment: oh yes yes.... It makes much sense now .. Thank you... :)

Comment: @Praphulla: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

First note that $|A|$ is at most $2^{\aleph_0}$, as any continuous function is determined by its values on the rationals. For the other inequality, consider the function $f_a(x)=a(x^2-x)$, we have $$|f'_a(x)|=|a(2x-1)|\leq |a|$$ It follows that $\{f_a: a\in [-1,1]\}\subseteq A$, so $2^{\aleph_0}\leq |A|$. It follows that $A$ has cardinality of the reals.

Comment: Why the down vote? This is a good answer.

Comment: I am confused... I do not understand this at all :O where is the condition that was specified that $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$ :O

Comment: @Rob: I don’t downvote, but it doesn’t answer the question: azarel overlooked the requirement that $f(1)=1$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: ... and so did I!